# Jenkins not able to connect sonarqube server

Tags: docker, jenkins, sonarqube, virtual-machine

I'm running **Ubuntu** on **Oracle VM** from my Windows 10 machine.

On Ubuntu, I'm running Jenkins in a docker container.

In this I've created a job which in which a I've added a **SonarScanner** build step.

In sonar configurations, I've mentioned a remote URL of my sonar server. Same URL can be opened in web browser without any problem.

I've also mentioned sonar project properties in the build step.

But when I execute the build, I get error, that jenkins is not able to connect sonar server.

But it's fishy since, I'm able to open same URL from my browser.

The jenkins setup & sonar configurations also seems to correct as same I've used in my native window's jenkins setup & it worked.

So I think it is something to do with VM, but not sure exactly what.
Any suggestions.

Also, on Ubuntu I'm working as a default user with admin access. (Not as root user)

*Thank you*

**Error Trace:**

```
10:34:27.358 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:167)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:113)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:73)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:58)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: sonarqube.intranet.myhost.com: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:137)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:82)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:113)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:98)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
    ... 10 more
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succedeed?
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Is this your sonarqube address 'sonarqube.intranet.myhost.com'? Have you configured that in your configuration file on the machine where you are running the Jenkins job. Also, Jenkins and SQ are running on same machine?

Comment: Can you ping 'sonarqube.intranet.myhost.com' from Jenkins machine?

Comment: @KrzysztofBłażełek, it's not myhost.com. I've changed it before posting the question. I'm not able to ping myhost, but traceroute was working.

Comment: Strange indeed. Just for testing purposes can you replace host name with it's IP? I.e. instead of http://sonar-host:9000 use http://1.2.3.4:9000.